# Firebase http cloud functions + Typescript async import + Express.js for max cold start performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, express

I use firebase http functions in my project and they work absolutely well. When I tried to improve performance I came across article from Mr. @DougStevenson in medium to [improve cold start performance by organising cloud functions in better way and using typescripts async importing of source file](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/organize-cloud-functions-for-max-cold-start-performance-and-readability-with-typescript-and-9261ee8450f0).

### Usual way of writing http calls using express js

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/placeOrder',  async (request: any, response: any) => {
    //something
});

//export this constant in index.ts
export const order = functions
    .region('asia-east2')
    .https
    .onRequest(app);
```

### Suggestion given by @DougStevenson to improve cold start performance

Index.ts

```
export const httpFn = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    await (await import('./fn/httpFn')).myFun(request, response)
})
```

Source file

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
admin.initializeApp()

export const myFun = async ( request: functions.https.Request
, response: functions.Response): Promise<void> => {

    const snapshot = await getDocument()
    const data = snapshot.data()
    response.send(data)
}
```

Both of them works absolutely well. But, when I tried to use the same approach with Express.js by using http post and get call asynchronously load the source file I am not able to do it and I am not able to find similar examples in my search.

I have tried

Index.ts

```
export const userOrder = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    await (await import('./order')).default(request, response)
});
```

order.ts

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/getOrder', async (request: any, response: any) => {
    response.status(200).send('It works!');
});
app.post('/createOrder', async (req: any, res: any) => {
    //something
});

export default app;
```

But this one is not working out and I would like to know how can I use Typescript's async import to deploy express js endpoints in cloud functions.

Thank you.

Comment: You're going to have to use a dynamic import for each route in the app, not one import for the entire app.  onRequest requires you to pass the app as its only argument.

Comment: But if i use simple dynamic import (like in the first example) instead of async import, can i achieve better cold start performance as you suggested in the article? Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I'm saying you **can't** do that, because you have to pass an app directly on onRequest.  Each route can have its own dynamic import, however.