# Firebase Functions: Could not create or update Cloud Run service, Container Healthcheck failed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

On `deploy` i got this error

```js
i  functions: creating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function addCourseData(us-central1)...
Could not create or update Cloud Run service addcoursedata, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'addcoursedata-00001-cup' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=PROJECT_ID&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/addcoursedata/revision_name/addcoursedata-00001-cup&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22addcoursedata%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22addcoursedata-00001-cup%22
For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        addCourseData(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
```

with `--debug` I got this log

```js
Total Function Deployment time: 67749
[] 1 Functions Deployed
[] 1 Functions Errored
[] 0 Function Deployments Aborted
[] Average Function Deployment time: 67748

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        addCourseData(us-central1)
[] Not printing URL for HTTPS function. Typically this means it didn't match a filter or we failed deployment

Functions deploy failed.
[] {
  "endpoint": {
    "id": "addCourseData",
    "project": "PROJECT_ID",
    "region": "us-central1",
    "entryPoint": "addCourseData",
    "platform": "gcfv2",
    "runtime": "nodejs18",
    "httpsTrigger": {},
    "labels": {
      "deployment-tool": "cli-firebase"
    },
    "serviceAccount": null,
    "ingressSettings": null,
    "availableMemoryMb": null,
    "timeoutSeconds": null,
    "maxInstances": null,
    "minInstances": null,
    "concurrency": 80,
    "vpc": null,
    "environmentVariables": {
      "FIREBASE_CONFIG": "{\"projectId\":\"PROJECT_ID\",\"databaseURL\":\"https://PROJECT_ID-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app\",\"storageBucket\":\"PROJECT_ID.appspot.com\"}",
      "GCLOUD_PROJECT": "PROJECT_ID",
      "EVENTARC_CLOUD_EVENT_SOURCE": "projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/us-central1/services/addCourseData"
    },
    "codebase": "default",
    "securityLevel": "SECURE_ALWAYS",
    "cpu": 1,
    "targetedByOnly": true,
    "hash": "38475170b79b25f455db5cacbdc1d6c36adc4679"
  },
  "op": "update",
  "original": {
    "name": "FirebaseError",
    "children": [],
    "exit": 1,
    "message": "Could not create or update Cloud Run service addcoursedata, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'addcoursedata-00001-sox' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=PROJECT_ID&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/addcoursedata/revision_name/addcoursedata-00001-sox&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22addcoursedata%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22addcoursedata-00001-sox%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
    "status": 3,
    "code": 3
  }
}
[] Error: Failed to update function addcourseData in region us-central1
    at C:\Users\USER_ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:51:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Fabricator.updateV2Function (C:\Users\USER_ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:380:32)
    at async Fabricator.updateEndpoint (C:\Users\USER_ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:153:13)
    at async handle (C:\Users\USER_ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:88:17)

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

How to fix it? Any help!

My code is

```js
const calledFunctionName = process.env.K_SERVICE;
if (!calledFunctionName || calledFunctionName === "addCourseData") {
  const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");

  // Take the email and adds an entry to Firestore with Course data
  exports.addCourseData = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    return await (await require("./my-functions/course/add-course-data-function"))
        .addCourseData(request, response);
  });
}
```

Everything was working fine before introducing the `process.env.K_SERVICE`, so is there anything else to do too, to use the environment variable? As I just added in code to save the cold start and unnecessary file loading.

Why server not able to create a container for the function?

Comment: The error message tells you to check the logs. Include the relevant log entries in your post.

Comment: May I know which logs, as I already included logs from `firebase-debug.log`

Comment: The error message also tells you which log has more details and provides you with a link to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to change this line

```js
if (!calledFunctionName || calledFunctionName === "addCourseData")
```

to

```js
if (!calledFunctionName || calledFunctionName === "addcoursedata")
```

OR (better approach would be)

```js
if (!calledFunctionName || calledFunctionName === "addCourseData".toLowerCase())
```

as **`process.env.K_SERVICE` returns the lower alphabets ONLY**, instead of camelCase or name-with-hyphens.

Finally, I found the answer to my issue after 2 days of researching and debugging. Maybe it saves someone's time!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have all the dependents you are using specified in package.json folder

"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
"firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
"nodemailer": "^6.9.7"
},

Same here I am using Nodemailer so I had to install it first in the functions' Dir

"message": "Could not create or update Cloud Run service sendemailonnewentry, Container Healthcheck failed. Revision 'sendemailonnewentry-00001-por' is not ready and cannot serve traffic.

MVH/Mouayad Mouayad

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also used the nodemailer and only installed outside the functions dir. Save me a lot time!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone meets this issue, please verify if all dependencies are installed before deploying.

Comment: Better to use the dependencies when you need it to get rid of long (& unnecessary) loading time overhead

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by npm package, somehow the package was not installed, but there were no compilation errors, locally it worked.

These dependencies were missing in my package.json, I am not sure ht it worked, without them.

```
@google-cloud/storage  
dayjs
```